# Recurrence rules (RRULE RFC 5545 iCalendar)

Tags: icalendar, recurrence, rfc5545

I'm trying to define a 4 week rotation from a set point in time, where that point in time might be inside week 2 of the rotation, the rotation itself is relative to an earlier date

Is it possible to have a single VEVENT with many RRULE rules but the RRULEs can begin their recurrence at different dates?

i.e. I'd like to have a rule that recurs every 4 weeks start on a date 
then I'd like another rule that recurs every 4 weeks, start a week after the first date and so on until 4 rules are actively recurring

Comment: If they are all in the same VEVENT isn’t this just a weekly recurring event? If each RRULE is 4 weeks and they just offset each a week after each other and there are 4 of them, in the 5th week one is at start of cycle 2 of the first RRULE?

Comment: Also stackoverflow suggests that one try things and report what you have tried and explicitly state what your error is. In this case you could handcode it and see what the ics validators and the major calendar providers do with it.

Comment: Actually the RFC 5545 spec says multiple RRules undefined https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5 so support from calendar apps might be variable.

Comment: I'm looking at multiple VEVENTS links with RELATED-TO but I suspect most clients won't treat them as a single entity, my example isn't very good it doesn't cover all permutations i.e. I may need to recur a week A, C and D week rotation